# Trying to filter DataTable with LINQ, am getting InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, telerik

I have a DataTable which I want to use as a DataSource for a Telerik RadGrid. However, I also need to filter some of the rows out, based on values from a couple of Telerik RadComboBoxes. So I'm trying to do this:

```
var bookings = BmBooking.GetByEventDateAndSection(EventDateId, 0).AsEnumerable().
    Where(b => b.Field<int>("StatusCode") >= Int32.Parse(cmbFromStatus.SelectedValue) &&
        b.Field<int>("StatusCode") <= Int32.Parse(cmbToStatus.SelectedValue));
```

The DataTable definitely has got an integer value (between 1 and 7) for every row. The SelectedValue of the ComboBoxes is "1" and "7", respectively.

This gives me an InvalidCastException. And of course Visual Studio won't tell me *what* cast goes wrong.

Comment: THe error suggest the `StatusCode` field is not an int, `Int.Parse` does not throw an `InvalidCastException` if the input is not valid, it throws a `FormatException`.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the field was a Byte.

Comment: If you want you can turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.